# Why do I get value of GDAL GetMaximum() different than that of numpy array max() for same image band?

Tags: python, gdal, python-script-tool, numpy, osgeo

Here is a code snippet

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy


file = gdal.Open('DEMO.TIF')
band = file.GetRasterBand(1)
max = band.GetMaximum()
if not min or not max:
    (min,max) = band.ComputeRasterMinMax(True)
print(max)

redArray = band.ReadAsArray()
maxArr = redArray.max()
print(maxArr)
```

Apparently both the max values need to be same as I am working on the same dataset and band. But I get the result as,

```
49820.0
53041
```

Why are these values not same?

Comment: What is your nodata value? Did you mask out the nodata?

Comment: no, I haven't masked out nodata values.  I am using Landsat Image. band.GetNoDataValue() returns me 0.

Comment: I believe that GetMaximum reads the max value from metadata and that can be wrong. Is the result the same if you force your code to use ComputeRasterMinMax?

Comment: @user30184 Yes the result is same when i use ComputeRasterMinMax()